# Running tests in PyCharm

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pycharm, automated-tests

I'm trying to run tests in PyCharm but I keep getting an arror that my test configuration file is non existent. However, as you can see in picture 3 below, the file is present and in the correct directory. These tests used to run with no issue so I think it must be the interpreter settings (picture 4). However, those appear to be correct too. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've added pictures below to show my setup (parts blanked out to protect my identity. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sooo, it was a simple user error. I had my working directory set to the wrong path. Don't work multiple late nights in a row people!